# How to insert html element inside innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html:

```
<div id="d1"></div>This is a text that <div id="d2"></div>needs to be manipulated
```

and two phrases from the text that indicates a start and end position, say in this example:

```
start = "a text"
end = "needs"
```

How can I use javascript to add a span element with a start tag just before the start phrase, and an end tag just after the end phrase, like this?

```
 <div id="d1">/div>This is <span id="phrase_1">a text that <div id="d2"></div>needs</span> to be manipulated
```

Comment: why omit `a` in `a text`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. I will fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the substrings exist in sibling [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) of the same [parent node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)?

Comment: @jsejcksn Yes, it can be assumed that substrings exists as you say.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75611735/how-to-insert-html-element-inside-innerhtml#comment133399057_75611735) @RoarSkullestad Ok, if it is also guaranteed that the start substring exists entirely within a single text node, and also that the end substring exists within a single different text node, then you could do something like this, which will preserve the integrity of all of the other nodes in the DOM: https://jsfiddle.net/9L2uez7o/

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75611735/how-to-insert-html-element-inside-innerhtml#comment133414230_75611735) If that fully addresses your question, then I can write it up as an answer. If not, what am I still missing?

Answer (score -1):

It would be interesting to know in what kind of parent element your initial html is included in. Because, if you can target that element.

if you can get the parent element, then you could do:

```js
parent.innerHTML.replace('a text', '<span>a text').replace('needs',  'needs</span>')
```

Comment: The parent is a div with an id.

Comment: Yes, this would work.

Answer (score -2):

use this

```js
const start = "a text"
const end = "needs"


const html = container.innerHTML

const indexStart = html.indexOf(start)
const indexEnd = html.lastIndexOf(end)

const newHTML =
  html.slice(0, indexStart)
+ `<span>${html.slice(indexStart, indexEnd + end.length)}</span>`
+ html.slice(indexEnd + end.length)

console.log(container.innerHTML = newHTML)
```

```css
span { color: red }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="d1"></div>This is a text that <div id="d2"></div>needs to be manipulated
</div>
```

Comment: This is very destructive to the existing DOM structure: it destroys and re-recreates all child nodes in the container node. It seems inconsequential in the example code, but could have quite negative side effects in other cases.

Comment: @jsejcksn it doesn't matter the OP's problem seems he needs to fix at system level dom

Comment: @jsejcksn it looks more like an editor than a website

Comment: @jsejcksn also why do you think the DOM is compiled? it could be a return result from a request

Comment: @jsejcksn are you trying to use TextNode? a pretty big cost when js has to search and read the entire node which is likely to be impossible to find